# Fatal error: Cannot instantiate abstract class DatabaseSchema in /home/myfoldername/public_html/demo/includes/database/database.inc on line 890

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I moved Drupal site files from local to server then when i run the site it show the error

> Fatal error: Cannot instantiate abstract class DatabaseSchema in /home/myfoldername/public_html/demo/includes/database/database.inc on line 890

Pls direct me on this

Comment: see if this link helps you https://drupal.org/node/1469058

Comment: Did you update your `settings.php` with the correct domain info and paths?

Comment: I have changed mysql details in settings.php..

Comment: As mentioned in the link i hae removed all modules folder but still its showing the same error

Answer (score 0):

Clear the cache using `drush cc`.